# Создание системы распознавания голоса

Tags: аудио, нейронные-сети

Решил сделать что то умное и полезное, а именно систему для распознавания речи. Хочется сделать качественно, так что прошу советов:

На каком языке писать что бы, в дальнейшем можно было бы легко перенести под *NIX и мобильные оси?

Что бы была хорошая библиотека для работы с аудио, а именно она должна:
- Работать со всеми распространёнными аудио форматами
- Работать с микрофоном
- С помощью нее можно было отфильтровать только голос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы разделил работу на два этапа: рисёрч и, собственно, реализация. Рисёрч я бы делал на чём-то вроде Java или C#, так как это очень сильно ускоряет разработку. Вы сможете сравнительно быстро реализовывать свои идеи и проверять их.

В случае, если удастся найти правильные решения, можно уже браться за проектирование реализации. И вот тут-то я бы советова взяться за C++, так как он действительно хорошо переносится. Разве что с iOS не уверен, что там у них.

"- С помощью нее можно было отфильтровать только голос" - если вы ставите такое условие к библиотеке дял работы со звуком, то это значит, что вы ещё ОЧЕНЬ далеки от темы. Ваша система должна уметь самостоятельно опознавать и отсеивать шумы. Никакая библиотека не может сделать это за вас. Единственное, что она могла бы сделать - это выделить определённый частотный диапазон, что, в общем, не гарантирует, что это обязательно голос.

Работать с микрофоном и читать разные форматы.. в Java для рисёрча есть всё необходимое. Уверен, что в C# тоже должно быть. Чтобы читать что-то сложнее, чем WAV, могут понадобиться кодеки. Это всё можно нарыть.

К сожалению, с кодеками могут начаться сложности в тот момент, когда речь пойдёт уже о финальной реализации и о всяких лицензиях. Стоит проявить осторожность в этом вопросе.

**UPD**

Напомнило старую шутку из абсурдопедии. В категории "как правильно" была старая статья про то, [как найти чёрную кошку в тёмной комнате](http://absurdopedia.wikia.com/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE:%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D1%83_%D0%B2_%D1%82%D1%91%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5). Среди вариантов, есть способ, использующий нейронные сети:

> Обучаем нейронную сеть путём показа кошек, пойманных другими методами. Обученная нейронная сеть будет способна ловить кошек без вмешательства человека **непостижимым для него способом**. Остаётся разместить сеть в тёмной комнате.

Comment: Но что-то я сомневаюсь что автор умнее googl'a и т.д. :)<br>
Если те до сиих пор не сделали приемлимой реализациии, то я очень сомневаюсь что у вас это полчится, не в обиду сказано...

Comment: @AlexWindHope, но можно же сделать что-то весьма простое, например для распознавания конкретного голоса с ограниченным набором вариантов.

Хороший и простой вариант на основе сетей Кохонена. Прост при расчетах.

Но, @cy6erGn0m прав, надо начать с теории цифровой обработки сигналов. Например, с голосовой модели, скажу наперед, что с гласными проблем на много меньше, чем с согласными звуками, ибо гласные представляются периодическими сигналами, а согласные - шумом. Отсюда вы уже пляшете и решаете, по каким характеристикам голоса/звука вам строить распознаватель.

Comment: Не выдавайте всех секретов!!!<br>
Ато гугл & company уже 100% следят за хэшкодом ^^